# Conservative obfuscations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am reading [this paper](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/solar/papers/semantic-malware.pdf).

Could someone please explain, at a high level, what **4.2.1 Conservative Obfuscations** does?

How is it different to non-conservative obfuscation?

Just a basic explanation is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather, a conservative obfuscation $\mathfrak O$ is an obfuscation where for any trace $\sigma$ of a program $P$, there exists a trace $\delta$ of the corresponding obfuscated program $\mathfrak O(P)$ such that every memory write and environment modification in $\sigma$ is also present in $\delta$. An example of a non-conservative obfuscation would be an algorithm that takes a C program compiled with GCC with low optimisation levels, somehow decompiles it into C and recompiles it with aggressive optimisations turned on. The resulting executable does inherently the same thing, but could possibly cut many memory writes as a result of optimisation.

Comment: I loved your answer, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, thanks for bringing this article to my attention, it's very interesting :) remember you can flag answers as accepted !

Comment: @Matrefeytonias Would you mind answering this question I found as I also need to know? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856706/what-does-this-semantic-do